# highgui complaining that it needs >=17.0.0 when I have 20.0

Tags: c, macos, opencv, dlopen, libpng

This is kind of an ugly one, but I am stuck so here it goes:

I am writing a dynamic library (henceforth 'mylib.dylib') that uses opencv (highgui and other parts) and is ultimately loaded by ffmpeg (libavfilter).  The library compiles just fine.  But when I try to dlopen() the dylib from within ffmpeg, I get the following error:

```
mylib.dylib: dlopen(mylib.dylib, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.3.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.3.dylib requires version 17.0.0 or later, but libpng15.15.dylib provides version 16.0.0
```

However, when I run **otool -L /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib**  I get the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib:
  /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib (compatibility version 20.0.0, current version 20.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.0.0)
```

Last time I checked, 20.0.0 is later than 17.0.0, which is what highgui said it requires.

I thought maybe it was an architecture problem (I am on a Mac running Lion, so I've encountered a lot of problems with i386/x86_64), but running 'file' on all of the libraries revealed that everything (highgui, libpng, mylib) is **Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64**

I thought perhaps there was some other version of libpng hiding on my system somewhere, but the dlopen error specifically points to /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib

There is obviously something that I am missing here -- admittedly I am no expert on how these dynamic libraries link. So if I forgot to include some pertinent info, please excuse me.

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention -- the lib works fine when I run ffmpeg through XCode (no dlopen error) which leads me to believe that it might have something to do with a environment variable that XCode is setting that I am not.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**
1. Don't be dumb
I was using MAMP and since I was calling ffmpeg through a php script, it was using its own set of dylibs, which (surprise surprise) included libpng 16.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar recently after I uninstalled all my MacPorts and installed updated versions. The problem was the version of libpng (1.2 vs 1.4 vs 1.5), not just the compatibility version. I had built OpenCV against libpng 1.4 (which is libpng14). I thought I could just use install_name_tool to make it look at libpng 1.5 (libpng15) instead but that didn't work. I ended up rebuilding OpenCV against the current versions of the library. That worked fine (after I remembered `sudo cmake install`).

(Some version numbers above might be incorrect but the gist is accurate.)

So either you don't have the version of libpng you originally had when you built OpenCV or it built against a libpng other than the one in /usr/local/lib (like maybe the one in /opt/local/lib). If that's the case you'll need to make sure you're building against the version you want to use. How to do that depends on your build method (MacPorts or cmake). I use cmake for OpenCV and MacPorts for other libraries which is why the two got out of sync on my system.

Comment: I uninstalled libpng and opencv using make (and did a manual search for any leftover files) and then reinstalled libpng-1.5.4, and then OpenCV-2.3.1.  I checked in the CMakeCache.txt for OpenCV and made sure that it was pointing to the brand new version of libpng.  Still getting an error, only now it's upgraded to 20.0.0+ whereas before it just wanted 17.0.0+!

So maybe on the right track? I don't use MacPorts or anything like that, and I just did a clean install recently when I upgraded to Lion, so if I have another version of libpng floating around, I have no idea where it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those who need the code:

```
cd  /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib
mv libpng15.15.dylib libpng15.15.dylib_old
ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib .
```